# MySQL on RDS / AWS (Amazon): performance_schema has no SQL_TEXT and QUERY_SAMPLE_TEXT

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, aws

We're using Mysql 8.0.32 on RDS, with Performance Insights and auto-managed performance_schema.

The performance_schema mostly works, but some fields are absent.

1. On performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest these fields are always empty:

- query_sample_text
- query_sample_seen
- query_sample_timer_wait

For example:

```
> SELECT distinct query_sample_text FROM performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_digest;
NULL
```

2. On performance_schema.events_statements_history_long, this field is always empty:

- sql_text

For example:

```
> select distinct sql_text from events_statements_history_long;
NULL
```

These tables do have the data, it's just these fields that are empty.

On the same version of MySQL, deployed on a regular server, outside of AWS RDS, these fields are not empty, they contain data about SQL queries.

I reviewed the server variables, and they seem to be good.

Do you observe the same on your RDS?

Any related AWS option/bug/feature, to fix it?